# Problem with pandas pivot_table Margin=True not giving me the correct answers

Tags: python, pandas

`pd.pivot_table(subset_one,index=["Institution_Types"],values=["Current_Balance"],aggfunc=([len, np.mean, max, min]),\ margins=True, margins_name='Total').reset_index()\ .rename(columns={'len': 'Loan Count', 'mean':'Average', 'max':'Max','min':'Min'})`

The total column is not giving the correct answer. See [My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EREnY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try to do you pivot table with `Margin=False` and add afterwards a line *Total* like this:

```py
pd.pivot_table(
    subset_one,
    index=["Institution_Types"],
    values=["Current_Balance"],
    aggfunc=([len, np.mean, max, min]),
    margins=False,
).reset_index().rename(
    columns={"len": "Loan Count", "mean": "Average", "max": "Max", "min": "Min"}
)
df = df.append(df.sum(axis=0), ignore_index=True)
df.iloc[-1, 0] = "Total"
```